# getExcerpt: Make ellipsis appear only if character limit is reached

Tags: functions, tags, excerpt, variables

I have a function called getExcerpt that displays the first 140 characters of an excerpt and after that, an ellipsis appears. The call in my template is like this:

```
 <?php echo get_excerpt(140); ?>
```

and my code in functions.php is:

```
function get_excerpt($count){
  $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
  $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
  $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
  $excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
  return $excerpt;
}
```

Works. However, if the excerpt is actually less than 140 chars, you still get the ellipsis. I only want it to appear if I have 140 or more chars. What variable do I have to put in to get that?

Comment: Use PHP's `mb_strlen` to get the actual excerpt length and only add the ellipsis, if the excerpt is 140 characters or more.

Comment: Why not to use [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) function and [`excerpt_more`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter? It seems that you are trying to do what `excerpt_more` filter was designed for.

Comment: Besides I just saw it on the `get_the_excerpt()` codex page, there is the function you want as one of the examples.

Comment: @cybmeta You do not have any information about the excerpt inside the `excerpt_more` hook. So it is not really practical for a condition grounded on the excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the length of the excerpt is longer than the max count.

```
if(strlen($excerpt) > $count){

 $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count) . '&#8230;';

}
```

`&#8230;` is the correct ellipsis character to use.

Comment: Yea,. my bad on not using &#8230; and thanks for that if statement.